# Why do I keep getting an overflow error when trying to calculate a value with a larger initial value?

Tags: python

I am completing an online course in Coursera and as part of a quiz, I have to change the initial conditions of the code.

The question:
The water depth was initially 1000 and the time step 100. The water depth had to be changed to 1 and the time step stepped down accordingly to avoid mathematical instability. I achieved this and the graph seemed stable at 1 m depth with a time step of 25. The initial temperature then has to be changed to 400 (temperature_list). I am trying to determine energyOutflux at a time of zero with these new initial conditions. With the initial temperature at 400 the Overflow calculation error occurs. The code is below:

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot 
#nSteps = int(input(""))

timeStep = 25                   # years
waterDepth = 1               # meters
heatCapacity = 4171448000       # J/m2K
L = 1350                        # W/m2
albedo = 0.3
epsilon = 1
sigma = 5.76E-8                 # W/m2 K4
energyInflux = L * (1-albedo)/4 # J/m2
yearSeconds = 31540000          # secs


time_list = [0]
temperature_list = [400]
energy_list = []
iSurfaceHeatT = heatCapacity * temperature_list[0]


for time in range(0,100):
    energyOutflux = (epsilon*(sigma)*pow(temperature_list[-1], 4)) # Outgoing flux
    deltaT = (energyInflux - energyOutflux) * timeStep * yearSeconds # flux change
    surfaceHeatT = iSurfaceHeatT + deltaT # surface heat content after time step
    planetaryT = surfaceHeatT / heatCapacity
    temperature_list.append(planetaryT + temperature_list[-1]) # add new planetary temperature value to last value in array
    time_list.append(timeStep + time_list[-1])
    energy_list.append(energyOutflux)
```

I keep receiving the following error:

```
    energyOutflux = (epsilon*(sigma)*pow(temperature_list[-1], 4)) # Outgoing flux
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Why is this error occurring and how can I complete the calculation?

Comment: Your numbers are probably too big. You need to find a way to make them smaller.

Comment: What is the value of `temperature_list[-1]`?

Comment: 0x5453 it is 400 initially but that it why the error occurs. I think because a number that size to the power of four is too big.